# Export data from salesforce into database

Tags: java, data-export

I am working in java. I am totally new to Salesforce.

I have requirement of exporting data (scheduling a job) from Salesforce and putting it into one database table.

I tried reading http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index.htm. But couldn't understand it, may be because of my lack of knowledge in this area.

Can anyone please help me in this. Can any one please provide me simple tutorial or sample example for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

the link you provided is for the Bulk API documentation. Therefore you will see that in the first paragraph of the introduction "The Bulk API provides programmatic access to allow you to quickly load your organization's data into Salesforce. " This allows you to IMPORT not export.
The simplest solution will be for you to use an additional tool called Data Loader that will allow you to export the org data in CSV format and then import this into your database.
You will need to decide is this a once off or regular export or will you be synching ultimately?
Additonally here is a good resource for you:
[Additonal Import/Export Resources for Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=import_which_data_import_tool.htm)

Comment: I have to create a scheduled job for exporting data from salesforce.

Comment: I would be a fan of Jitterbit's Connect for Salesforce it supports bidirectional data so that you can schedule exports from Salesforce to a database, Text, XML or LDAP (http://www.jitterbit.com/Docs/WebHelp/Wizards/Salesforce_Query_Wizard.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are several different ways to integrate separate but related application systems at the data layer. For example, any number of apps can access a single shared database and efficiently manage data in real time. In contrast, when each app must maintain its own database, or when you want to import or export large amounts of data, mechanizing the transfer of data among pertinent systems helps preserve the consistency and quality of data across the entire organization.

There are various various data integration options related to Salesforce platforms.
Open APIs (SOAP, REST, Streaming, etc.)
Bulk Data Transfer API
Language-Specific Resources and Toolkits (Java, JavaScript, Ruby, etc.)
Cloud-to-Cloud Integration Toolkits (Amazon, Facebook, Google, etc.)

Salesforce Library Extract : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Integration

This has tutorials and insight on all the above listed options.

Cheers